# AWS EC2 FTPS set up

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ftp

I can connect to my server using normal FTP but not on FTPs (I believe I need a certificate) I have opened ports on the server:

- 22 ssh
- 20 - 21 tcp
- 50000 - 51000 tcp
- tcp 990

I am using EC2, I am using `vsftpd` and set the `.conf` file like I think I ought to (I followed [silicon dales tutorial](https://silicondales.com/tutorials/aws-ec2/setup-ftp-sftp/)).

Could anyone point me the right direction? Like how to get a certificate and where to put it etc and whether the `.conf` needs to be updated?

The error I currently get when trying to connect to port 990 from Filezilla is:

> Connection attempt failed with "ECONNREFUSED - Connection refused by server".

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue solved: I did it by using these commands on the server:

1. mkdir -p /etc/vsftpd/ssl
2. cd /etc/vsftpd/ssl
3. openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout vsftpd-private.pem -out vsftpd-cert.pem

I also edited the vsftpd.conf file adding:

```
one_process_model=no
ssl_enable=YES
allow_anon_ssl=NO
force_local_data_ssl=YES
force_local_logins_ssl=YES

ssl_tlsv1=YES
ssl_sslv2=NO
ssl_sslv3=NO
require_ssl_reuse=NO
ssl_ciphers=HIGH
rsa_cert_file=/etc/vsftpd/ssl/vsftpd-cert.pem
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/vsftpd/ssl/vsftpd-private.pem
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be your SecurityGroups.
Based on this [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-vsftpd-for-a-user-s-directory-on-ubuntu-16-04) post, it looks like you have to open port range 40000-50000 for vsftpd.